# Attaching NFA Fragments together (Thompson)

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, nfa

I've read a lot about NFA's and DFA's, and I wanted to implement one in Python. I chose Python because it is very useful when simulating algorithms. So, using Thompson's construction algorithm, I implemented States with their transitions and also built NFA Fragments that represent a different part of a regular expression. One for a symbol transition and one for concatenation. Except I got stuck at the concatenation part, because the states that I tried to "glue" together don't match, and they point to different objects.

[image: Thompson's algorithm for concatenation]

This is what it should be, but for me the `q0` start node of `N(s)` doesn't transition into it's end node, which is the `N(t)` start node.

Here is my code, all in one file for simplicity:

```
class State(object):

def __init__(self, label, isfinish, trans):
    self.label = label
    self.trans = trans
    self.isfinish = isfinish
    self.id = label + str(id(self))

NFA_SIMULATE_RUN = False

class NFA(object):

    def __init__(self, tup):
        self.Q = tup[0]
        self.S = tup[1]
        self.start = tup[2]
        self.end = tup[3]
        self.table = {}

        for state in self.Q:
            trans_list = {}
            if not state.isfinish:
                for sym in state.trans.keys():
                    trans_list[sym] = state.trans[sym]
            self.table[state] = trans_list

    def move(self, state, sym):
        assert(state in self.Q),(state + " is not in state set")
        assert(sym in self.S),(sym + " is not in alphabet")
        if sym not in self.table.keys():
            if '' in self.table.keys():
                sym = ''
        possible_states = self.table[state][sym]
        if NFA_SIMULATE_RUN:
            i = random.randint(0, len(possible_states) - 1)
            chosen_state = possible_states[i]
            return chosen_state
        return possible_states

    def accepts(self, string):
        curstate = self.start
        for ch in string:
            curstate = self.move(curstate, ch)
        if curstate.isfinish:
            print(string + " accepted!")
        else:
            print(string + " rejected!")

class SymbolNFA(NFA):

    def __init__(self, sym):
        self.end = State('qf', True, {})
        self.start = State('q0', False, {
            sym: self.end
        })
        self.Q = [self.start, self.end]
        self.S = [sym]
        super(SymbolNFA, self).__init__((self.Q, self.S, self.start,                 self.end))

class ConcatNFA(NFA):

    def __init__(self, nfa1, nfa2):
        self.end = nfa2.end
        nfa1.end = nfa2.start
        self.start = nfa1.start
        self.Q = [self.start, nfa1.end, self.end]
        self.S = list(set(nfa1.S) | set(nfa2.S))
        super(ConcatNFA, self).__init__((self.Q, self.S, self.start,     self.end))



def main():
    nfa1 = SymbolNFA('a')
    nfa2 = SymbolNFA('b')
    nfa3 = ConcatNFA(nfa1, nfa2)
    print("NFA 1:\n" + str(nfa1.table))
    print("NFA 2:\n" + str(nfa2.table))
    print("NFA 3:\n" + str(nfa3.table))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
NFA 1:
{<__main__.State object at 0x7f1ce99645c0>: {'a': <__main__.State object at 0x7f1ce9964588>}, <__main__.State object at 0x7f1ce9964588>: {}}

NFA 2:
{<__main__.State object at 0x7f1ce9964668>: {'b': <__main__.State object at 0x7f1ce9964630>}, <__main__.State object at 0x7f1ce9964630>: {}}

NFA 3:
{<__main__.State object at 0x7f1ce99645c0>: {'a': <__main__.State object at 0x7f1ce9964588>}, <__main__.State object at 0x7f1ce9964668>: {'b': <__main__.State object at 0x7f1ce9964630>}, <__main__.State object at 0x7f1ce9964630>: {}}
```

(Sorry for the object printing, I didn't quite figure out how to coordinate all the states together.)

As you can see, for the first 2 Nfa's, the symbol fragments, their start state transitions correctly to the end state object through their symbol. But when I concatenate them, the state specified after the first transition ('a' in that case) is not the middle state, (end of first nfa, start of second nfa). It points to some random state object that I coudln't locate. The state specified after the 'b' transition though is correct, and points correctly to the whole nfa's end state.

To better understand the output, just interpret it as an FA Transition Table.

Any help is appreciated, and I'll let you know that it's only my first few times working with algorithms of the sort, so I am probably missing something.

Comment: You've written `if not state.isfinish:`. I think this is wrong. It's perfectly possible to have a transition out of an end state. End state just means that if it ends in that state we conclude that the string matches the regex. If there are more characters then the automaton will continue until they are all used, and then it will check whether that final state is a valid end state. So I think the inner `for` loop should run in all cases.

Comment: Well, you have a choice here: either introduce [epsilon transition](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37470/how-does-an-nfa-use-epsilon-transitions) and use it to connect end of A with start of B (the easiest way); or you can really "glue together" these states by choosing one of them as "canonical" and rewriting all mentions of the second.

Comment: Actually my previous comment isn't important - in Thompson NFAs it is true that an end state has no outgoing transitions.

Comment: @yeputons Does that mean that basically I replace one of the two "glued" objects by the contents and transitions of the other?

Comment: @yeputons Thanks, that fixed it (for now).